# Would I say "I can sometimes..." or "I sometimes can..."

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I'm just curious.  I like to think that I am decent with grammar, but this has me puzzled.

**Which is the correct way to arrange my sentence?**

*"I can sometimes..."*

or

*"I sometimes can..."*

Thank you

Comment: There is no "correct" way. Both are acceptable, both mean the same thing, and both are equally colloquial and normal. Which one gets used depends -- in my experience, anyway; YMMV -- on whether the speaker wants a `d'DA-duh` phrase or a `DA-d'duh` phrase. In other words, not difference. Your mistake is in believing that there has to be a **correct way to arrange your sentences**. I agree it'd be convenient if there were such a thing, but no such luck. Most of the time it's speaker's choice, and it's an esthetic choice, not a grammatical one.

Comment: I was thinking that both were interchangeable, but I kept second guessing myself.  I usually use the first; the second seems more formal...to me anyway.  I just wanted to be certain that I wasn't making any mistakes.  Thanks @JohnLawler

Comment: @JohnLawler, this comment (and the one below) has influenced readers, and OP to accept  an incorrect answer, the 3 options are not on the same footing and, since there are dots here (which imply a 'main verb' is following), it is not a mere esthetic choice. There *are* rules to arrange sentences, with some exceptions, of course

Comment: I already voted your answer up. I can't do it again. What do you mean by "incorrect", and why do  you think that answer is "incorrect"? It is certainly right that neither of the two combinations is ungrammatical, and either may be used in any sentence where one of them would be grammatical. By the way, I am aware of at least [some of the rules used to arrange sentences](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf).

Comment: @JohnLawler, votes are for students. I asked you to correct your proposition suggesting that in this case "it's an esthetic choice". There is a rule, and: "I can **s..** go" is the canonical form (as in N.Coward's quote), "**s..** I can go" is also correct, but "I s.. can go"/ "I s.. have gone" / "I **s..** do not"  are *not* on the same footing. That's why the accepted answer is misleading for future readers (and OP). As you also agree in your latest comment, *ngrams* and *google searches** do not make grammar: ["I ain't"] gives some 30,000,000 hits

Comment: @surf: You seem to believe that there is some Authority somewhere that produces English Grammar Rules that are Correct and mandates that they be Obeyed and Enforced. This is the kind of nonsense used by ignorant teachers to scare students. If you know the Correct rules, please inform everyone where they came from, why they're the Correct rules, and why we should pay any attention to your opinions on them.

Comment: @JohnLawler, I thought you said you are aware of some rules, but now I understand, it is really  an "esthetic choice".

Comment: As I said, I am aware of **real** grammar rules, but there are too many nonsense rules to pay attention to. And they're all contradictory anyway. Here is [a selection of actual rules, with examples, of English syntax](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf). These are attested and accepted.

Comment: After all this time and discussion, I see that nobody asked the poster what his sentence actually was. It may not make a difference, but sloppy questions need improving, ignoring or closing. I’ll put my money where my mouth is…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, there's no "correct" way here...

Both of those, plus - what I would argue as the most popular option - "*Sometimes I can*" are all OK in my book.

> - *I can sometimes see the future but it's not working today.*
> - *I sometimes can eat an entire pizza alone.*
> - *Sometimes I can spell complicated words without needing the spellchecker!*

A lot of the time, I'd say that the version you choose will depend on the word you want to emphasize.

Of the three, I'd say that the first and third are the more common constructions... which this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20can%20sometimes%2CI%20sometimes%20can%2Csometimes%20I%20can&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20can%20sometimes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20sometimes%20can%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csometimes%20I%20can%3B%2Cc0) seems to agree with.

[image: NGram of three options]

Comment: Thanks!  Apparently, I need to wait another 3 minutes before I can accept this answer? haha

Comment: @JohnManly You should always wait a few hours or even a day before accepting answers. Fast answers aren't always **good** answers! Let people vote and see if anyone else has an opinion.

Comment: Just afraid I might forget to accept, if no one else does anything with this question.  I'll be sure to check back tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is rather complex.

There are some rules that regulate the position of an [adverb of frequency](https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/word-order/adverb-position), such as: sometimes, often, occasionally, always etc.

```
 subject aux/be  adverb   main verb  object/place/time


  I             *often*     go swimming        in the evenings.
  He    doesn't *always*    play      tennis.
  We    are     *usually*   here               in summer.
   I    have    *never*     been           abroad.
```

but real usage is different for each one of them. One first distinction must be made between adverbs of frequency that can be used at the beginning (less frequently at the end) of the sentence, an adverbs that cannot.

In the example in question there is a [modal verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs#Usage_of_specific_verbs) *can* which functions as an *auxiliary verb* and therefore the correct position of the adverb should be between the *aux* and the *main verb*, as in this quote from [Noel Coward](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/n/noelcoward128225.html):

"*I'm not a heavy drinker, I can sometimes go for hours without touching a drop*."

```
     You    can    *never*    leave
     I      can    *usually*  drink
     I      can    *sometimes* go
```

But,

- *sometimes* is one of the frequency adverbs that can be placed at the beginning of the sentence, and this is felt more natural by many native speakers, and, in addition,
- it is an exception to the rule, since it has a peculiarity of its own: it *must* be placed at the beginning in a negative sentence, you say:

  1. I do not [always / usually / often / frequently / regularly / generally] go to church.
  2. I have not [always / usually / often / frequently / regularly / generally] gone to bed after midnight.
  3. I can't [always / usually / often / frequently / regularly / generally] go for hours...

but, if you want to use *sometimes* in all these examples, you have to place it right at the beginning. You don't say:

"I don't sometimes go to church", "I have not sometimes gone..", "I can't sometimes go for hours", but you say: "*sometimes I don't/have not/can't..."

Any other position, including the one suggested by the general rule, is felt as wrong.

The non-negligible presence of the incorrect *I sometimes can....*" in the ngram quoted in another answer is due to the fact that it is quite correct in an answer: "*Can you go for.*.." - "*Sure, I sometimes can!*"
If you consider it a modal verb followed by another verb, the result of the [* ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+can+sometimes+go%2CI+sometimes+can+go%2Csometimes+I+can+go&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=50&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20can%20sometimes%20go%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csometimes%20I%20can%20go%3B%2Cc0) is different and gives "Not found" for the wrong form, and the other two are on the same level.

[image: Ngram screenshot]

The representation of the three variants in the other ngram is misleading, since it suggests all of them are correct.

Lastly if you search for another adverb *occasionally* in the truncated, ambiguous form : "*I occasionally can...*" you get ["Not found"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+occasionally+can%2Coccasionally+I+can%2CI+can+occasionally&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=50&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coccasionally%20I%20can%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20can%20occasionally%3B%2Cc0), which confirms, in a way, the peculiarity of *sometimes*

Comment: That rule you propose for negative sentences only works if you want to keep the quantifier inside the scope of the negative; and you often will. But if you want the quantifier outside, you **can** say _I always / usually / often / frequently / regularly / generally don't go to church._ Of course that means something different. But "a negative sentence" is insufficiently specific, when dealing with quantifier placement. Negation and quantification interact in very odd ways, being [logical operators](http://www,umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf).

Comment: @JohnLawler,  The subject of 'must' is *sometimes*, the sentence is saying that you don't say:"I have not sometimes...gone",  "I don't sometimes go..." , "I sometimes don't go to church" , while you can say: "I don't usually go...",. If it is not clear I'll edit. Let me know if you agree.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I was looking for an ungrammatical example and didn't count the variables in the grammatical one.  This is why linguists use ungrammatical examples and mark them with asterisks. You're correct, **I don't sometimes go to church* and  **She can't sometimes force herself to eat it* are ungrammatical. Sorry about that.

Comment: I never downvote anything; I'm not here to judge students but to answer questions. I'm done judging my students, and none of them are here anyway. But +1 for sure.

Comment: **All** ngrams are misleading. They're not evidence for anything but arbitrary fashions in writing, especially if one searches for particular words instead of variables. All language is spoken, not written; this point gets lost frequently on a site like this one. Consequently, data about written language does not normally touch on grammar.

Comment: @JohnLawler, You surely have posted this comment in the wrong place, since I tried, with this answer, to show how the superficial use of ngrams can be misleading, and you and you surely didn't help me, so far, with your superficial and hasty comments. I did quote some rules, if you think my source is incorrect, written and "*...used by ignorant teachers to scare students...*", just disprove them.

Comment: [Your source](https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/word-order/adverb-position) is full of nonsense rules. It appears not to notice that there is any variation in speech, and it chooses one construction for each type of word, and asserts that that is the only correct choice. That's, as I said, nonsense. First example says adverbs of manner go at the end of the verb phrae, which they can; but they can go in other places, too, quite grammatically. The exercise would say that _Quietly they slipped out of the house_ is ungrammatical; it's not. And so on and so on. Safe, but not Correct.

Comment: I sometimes can see you from my window. Let's dig a big pit and bury ngrams in it. It is music to my ears to hear that "all language is spoken, not written". And, of course,  you can put 50 people in a room and ask them how they would say something. One technique. Or: you can keep your ears open and listen to people in general over time.  And compare what you hear to what you have internalized over time. There is no great big grammar ear in the sky listening to how people talk. Should I say yet? Ugh. It "they" can get  us, "they" will.

Answer (score 1):

"Sometimes" is bad toward the middle:

> sometimes the fish must have been being eaten for hours
>   the fish sometimes must have been being eaten for hours
>   the fish must sometimes have been being eaten for hours
>   the fish must have sometimes been being eaten for hours
>   *the fish must have been sometimes being eaten for hours
>   *the fish must have been being sometimes eaten for hours
>   the fish must have been being eaten sometimes for hours
>   the fish must have been being eaten for hours sometimes

McCawley in **The Syntactic Phenomena of English** gives a theory of adverbs that makes "sometimes" (and all time adverbs) modifiers of V-bar which can optionally be raised to be sentence modifiers.  That predicts that all the patterns I've just listed should be acceptable.  IMO, here, and overall, McCawley's theory doesn't work very well.  I have my own theory of adverbs which, unfortunately, doesn't work very well to predict facts of adverb placement, either.  It's a difficult problem.

Comment: It's worse if the fish is bad in the middle.

Comment: What is truly awful is: the fish must have been being eaten. Unless of course there is contextual justification for it.